# mysql and php views

Tags: mysql, view

i am writing a html form, that simply passes data to a php one, and then to an sql database.
my question is, should view be stored in php or sql (and call them from php)?
i could do that. the problem is that in my views i have variables. i.e each time i call them i have different parameters in them.

so my php code looks like this:

```
$this->query = "SELECT student.gender FROM student WHERE email ='$this->email'";
```

if i put the above view in mysql, i can't use a variable like "email" right?

so where are view better to be stored?
same goes for procedures ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->query = sprintf("SELECT student.gender FROM student WHERE email ='%s'", $this->email);
```

Comment: so im guessing, no storing in sql